# Converting between rotation representations

Tags: drake

What's the best way in Drake to convert between rotation representations? e.g. quaternion to rotmat, quaternion to RPY, etc.

In the ideal case, whatever method proposed would also work with all autodiff funcitonality.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using `eigen::Quaternion`, `drake::math::RollPitchYaw`, `drake::math::RotationMatrix`, the drake classes have functions to convert between the representations.  Each of the classes can be used with `double` or `AutoDiffXd`.